Google Search Console 'See Page Indexing' Option Disabled and No Traffic Recorded
I purchased a domain about two month ago and started working on the site right away. Despite not submitting my website to Bing Search Console, I'm receiving traffic from Bing. However, I've added the site to Google Search Console and fetched every URL, yet I'm still not seeing any queries, impressions, or clicks.
Moreover, the "See Page Indexing" option in Google Search Console is not enabled, meaning I can't click on it. Although I regularly update my content, the sitemap only reflects the last crawl date when it was manually fetched, and it doesn't automatically crawl on the latest date. This is concerning because my other website, which operates in the same niche, is being crawled daily without any issues.

So, let's go through the following four points. Are you sure everything is okay with them?
Domain Verification Issues
If your domain isn’t verified correctly in Google Search Console, indexing data may be unavailable.
Check your verification method in Search Console settings to ensure it matches your current site setup. Re-verify if necessary.
Indexing Errors
noindex tags, robots.txt blocks, or URL parameters might be hindering indexing.
Check robots.txt files and noindex tags on pages that should be indexed. Make sure they’re crawlable.
Technical Site Errors
Slow page loads, server errors (5xx), or HTML issues can prevent indexing.
Use the crawl report and “URL Inspection” tool in Search Console to identify and fix loading issues.
Incorrect Site Structure
Duplicate content, confusing internal links, or poor site structure can affect indexing.
Optimize your site’s structure, fix duplicate content, and organize internal links. Use canonical URLs to resolve duplicates.
And one more question, did I understand correctly that your Sitemap isn’t updating automatically?
